# boost python libraries build

Tags: c++, python, boost

I am using an ubuntu 10.04, with the gcc toolset version 4.4.3

My boost installation is at

```
/usr/local/boost_1_50_0
```

I am looking to build the python libraries. For this, in my installation folder i instructed

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
```

To which I received the following reply

```
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/v2/engine/bin.linuxx86/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.6
Detecting Python root... /usr
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Backing up existing Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam.6
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

./b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

- Command line help:
  ./b2 --help

- Getting started guide: 
  http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

- Boost.Build documentation:
  http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/index.html

 aditya@aditya:/usr/local/boost_1_50_0$ g++ --version
 g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
 Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I then perform

```
 sudo ./b2
```

I then receive a host of build errors - basically nothing builds.

I suspect this is to do with the unavailability of some of the python dev libraries.

This machine is not connected to the internet, so I'll need to build these myself (as opposed to sudo apt-get install them).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you need help finding a python-devel package for Ubuntu?

Comment: @SamMiller Thanks, I managed to solve the issue. Built python from source ...